# Compare unique data for column in between two sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to compare unique data for column A in between two sheets.

If the data is unmatched, then delete the cell value in Sheet2.

Can anyone help?

```
Sheet1
  A     B   C   D
a1ab1   a1  a   b1
a2ab2   a2  a   b2
a3ab3   a3  a   b3

Sheet2 
  A     B   C   D
a1ab1   a1  a   b1
a2ab2   a2  a   b2
        a5  a   b5
        a6  a   b6
        a7  a   b7
a3ab3   a3  a   b3
a4ab4   a4  a   b4
         a8 a   b8
         a9 a   b9
        a10 a   b10
```

```
Sub compare()
    Dim names As Long, values As Long, i, j As Long

    names = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    values = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To names
        For i = 2 To values
            If Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1).value <> Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).value Then
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1).value = "New"
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your code?

Comment: This question comes up occasionally and there are a few ways to accomplish it. However, the operative question always boils down to **Why not simply replace Sheet2's data with the data from Sheet1? Are there records in Sheet1 that should not be in Sheet2?** Your sample data does not support the fact that there may be data in Sheet1 that does not belong in Sheet2 and that fact is important in suggesting hte correct course of action for you. Additionally, are there column header labels? Your sample data shows none.

Comment: I'm trying to create a workbook which consists two sheets in which Sheet1 represents for yesterday data and Sheet2 represents for today's data. Sheet2 is the data being copied from database. The purpose for my excel vba is to let the user know which one is the most updated data. Therefore, if data exists in Sheet1 but not Sheet2 will indicate the word "New" in front of the row.

Comment: OK, your code actually says **Sheet3**, not **Sheet2** but that is a minor point. The biggest thing I do not understand is that your narrative states that *'If the data is unmatched, then delete the cell value in Sheet2'* but neither your code or your recent comment says anything about deleting rows.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I meant Sheet3. Also, if data is unmatched, then write the word "New" to the corresponding first column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want to  "New" blank values?
I would use a Find and loop through the values on Sheet3. I've tried to style my script similar to how you wrote it. Hope it makes sense.

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim names As Range, values As Long, j As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set names = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    values = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        For j = 2 To values
            If names.Find(What:=.Range("A" & j).Value, _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
            And .Range("A" & j).Value <> "" _
            Then .Range("A" & j).Value = "NEW"
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```